# Stop UI auto resize with java.awt using Netbeans builder

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I just made an UI using netbeans interface builder, it uses java.awt for the interface components. The problem I have is that once I run the application it looks like this:

[image: Start UI]

But then after filling the textfields it may autoresize it, not instantly but whenever I click near to it:

[image: Problem UI]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Dimension d = textField.getPreferredSize();  
textField.setMaximumSize(d);
```

Or:

```
textField.setColumns(10) //change 10 to whatever suits you ;)
```